# Can I pass an object into my method using Unity AOP?

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-container, aop

I use AOP with WCF to log calls so all my webservices log in the same way.

The log starts writing when the call is intercepted, with details of what's going on, then after it returns, it writes a log saying it has finished along with any exceptions the webservice may have thrown.

What I'd like to do is pass my `Logger` object into the webservice itself to add a few extra log statements of its own.

Is this possible using AOP?

The code is:

```
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, 
GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        Logger someLogger = new Logger();
        return getNext()(input, getNext);
    }
```

I'd like to either get someLogger into the getNext() method which is my webservice, or be able to access it from a global context - but the global context won't work since the webservice can process many requests at once.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason why you can't just inject an `ILogger` as a dependency in the web service?

Comment: I believe the webservice can do something like 20 simultaneous connections at once, and each logger basically gathers information then writes it all to the database. If I used a single logger it would mix all the different simultaneous calls up. Unless I'm not understanding your reply.

Comment: I guess George means that if you're resolving your WCF service type via Unity you could use Unity to pass in an instance of your Logger as part of the resolution process. You could control the lifetime of the Logger via Unity - a singleton, a new instance each time etc.

Comment: It's possible I don't understand enough about this to be able to work out how to do that. I think you're saying that in my instance provider, which creates the service in order to do AOP I pass a logger into the constructor. Then I can call it in my AOP? If the AOP runs the constructor before getNext() then I guess I can do that! I can't see how to access the object from the AOP code though, given the method signature in the original post.

Comment: I don't like mixing DI and AOP this way. Is the WCF `OperationContext` available to you? It would be a safe instance specific context for both the logger and the service.

Comment: It should be possible. Register the `ILogger` with the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` which can give you one `Logger` per web request.

Comment: That looks great. At the moment I popped it into the constructor and accessed it via `((MyService)input.Target).Logger` but it is not ideal. This looks much better, thanks.